# Complex wmi queries using execquery

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, wmi

In powershell I can do a query like

```
> get-wmiobject -query 'select * from win32_groupuser' | % {[wmi]$_.partcomponent|select domain,name,SID}
```

Which will list for each wmi, the domain, name and sid for each user.

How would I accomplish this using vbscript?

I currently use `execquery`:

```
Dim strComputer, objWMIService
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
objWMIService.ExecQuery("select partcomponent,groupcomponent from win32_groupuser")
```

for the first part, but how do I incorporate the equivalent of `| % {[wmi]$_.partcomponent|select domain,name,SID}`

Alternatively, how could I do

```
gwmi win32_groupuser | % { [wmi]$_.partcomponent | select domain,name,sid}
```

using vbscript; as it is not a query, I cannot use `execquery`, but it has the same output as the original query.

Answer (score 0):

[`ASSOCIATORS OF` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384793(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The `ASSOCIATORS OF` statement retrieves all instances that are
>   associated with a particular source instance. The instances that are
>   retrieved are referred to as the endpoints. Each endpoint is returned
>   as many times as there are associations between it and the source
>   object.

**Sample script**:

```
option explicit
Dim sResult, strComputer, objWMIService, group, groups, user, users
sResult = ""

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject(_
  "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set groups = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_Group" )
For Each group in groups
  Set users = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Associators of {Win32_Group.Domain='" & group.Domain _
        & "',Name='" & group.Name & "'} " _
        & "Where AssocClass = Win32_GroupUser ResultRole = PartComponent")
  For Each user in users
    sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & group.Domain & " " & group.Name _
        & vbTab & user.Name & vbTab & user.SID
  Next
Next

Wscript.Echo sResult
```